# Как поисковые системы кешируют SPA приложения написанные на reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, поисковые-системы, поисковая-оптимизация

С сайтами на php тут всё понятно - поисковая система запрашивает урл, сервер выдаёт готовую html страницу, где уже есть контент страницы. SPA приложение же отдаёт пустую html страницу (в плане контента) и контент генерируется уже при помощи js на стороне клиента. Запускает ли поисковый бот js скрипт на своей стороне чтобы получить требуемую структуру страницы или же бот видит только чистый html?

Answer (score -1):

> Запускает ли поисковый бот js скрипт на своей стороне чтобы получить
>   требуемую структуру страницы или же бот видит только чистый html?

Нет не запускает, он видит чистый HTML.

Для того чтобы у бота был контент надо воспользоваться технологией SSR (server side rendering). Приложения с использованием этой технологии называются изоморфными.